Error en arduino "was not declared in this scope"
estamos haciendo códigos para hacer que un display cuente del 0 al 9 cada uno con un segundo,o que sucede es que me presenta un error y no se qué es, help trato de resolverlo pero no funciona y cuando lo "arreglo" y le doy a comprobar me dice otro error no seee :(

cabe destacar que no se nada de esto de los códigos o programación

¿Has definido una función "borrar()" (O las funciones "cero()", "uno()", "dos()", etc.?

cabe destacar que no se nada de esto de los códigos o programación No es necesario decirlo.


[error404] nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta. 2. El código y los mensajes de error siempre como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.


El error se debe a que el compilador ha detectado que no has definido una función borrar(). Por lo que muestras, sí has definido las funciones uno(), dos(), etc. Así que debes definir una función como esas pero para añadir la funcionalidad para borrar la información mostrada en el display.
Un consejo para las siguientes preguntas que hagas, es poner todo el código, así la gente sabrá de manera más fácil cual es el problema en u código.
Puedes usar el siguiente código que creo que hace lo que quieres hacer.
// Biblioteca para controlar el display de siete segmentos
#include <SevSeg.h>

// Definimos los pines a los que está conectado el display de siete segmentos
// Estas son constantes, puedes modificarlos de acuerdo a tus necesidades
#define NUM_DIGITS 1
#define DIGIT_1 2
#define SEG_A 3
#define SEG_B 4
#define SEG_C 5
#define SEG_D 6
#define SEG_E 7
#define SEG_F 8
#define SEG_G 9

// Creamos un objeto de la clase SevSeg
SevSeg display;

void setup() {
    // Configuramos el objeto SevSeg
    display.Begin(COMMON_CATHODE, NUM_DIGITS, DIGIT_1, SEG_A, SEG_B, SEG_C, SEG_D, SEG_E, SEG_F, SEG_G);

   // Se puede configurar el brillo si es que tu quieres jejejej
   display.SetBrightness(100);
}

void loop() {
    // Ciclo For para mostrar los numeros del 1 al 10
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    // Mostramos el numero en el display
    display.WriteDigitNum(0, i);
    delay(1000); // 1 segundo de espera

    // Borramos el display
    display.WriteDigitNum(0, (uint8_t)0x0F); // 0x0F es el código para borrar
    delay(100); // 100 ms para mostrar el siguiente numero
    }
}


Al parecer no has declarado la funcion borrar(), quizas sea que tengas la funcion con otro nombre. toma en cuenta que para el compilador las mayusculas/minusculas son diferentes. no el lo mismo borrar() que Borrar().
